# Is it possible to run an asp.net project with a link in local?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, local, publish, localdb

I have a project on Asp.net core. I did it for someone but I don't want to publish the website.

Is it possible to put the code on his computer with a local db and make sure that he can access the site on local with a link?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure it is. Just about anything is possible. Now that we've answered that, do you have a followup question?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest publishing the webapp to a local instance of IIS that way it is accessible via localhost and will continuously run.

This link should help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis